# How to stop System update on Firefly intense 5

Tags: applications

My phone is Firefly Intense 5 and I received a notification of system update. I accidentally hit it so my phone starts updating. Now, it suddenly turns off because it's low bat.And up until now, it is still updating. The update starts last Wednesday, now it's Friday. Is there any way I can stop it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Go to Settings
- Then applications (or app)
- Sweep to **Running apps**
- Locate `SystemUpdateService` then stop it. (click on stop)
- Go back to **Download apps**
- Locate `Google Play Service` and `Clear All Data`
- Now go check at **Settings > About > Software update**. You should see the update there just don't hit on download.